# Alarm Manager doesn't fire notifications when I set date

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to set notifications at specific date and time.

Notifications are working only when I set to calendar values for hour and minute , but not date.
here is example from my code

```
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);

    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long time = cal1.getTimeInMillis();

    AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AddReminder.REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));
    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, broadcast);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java calender month starts from 0 , so if you want October to be the month , it will be 9 not 10

```
cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
```